# Showing Android's soft keyboard when a field is .focus()'d using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, android-softkeyboard

In a web-page I've got a search field. I've added a "clear" button so that users can clear the search field and start again. As a convenience, I focus the search field's text box and the cursor does appear in the box. However the soft keyboard does not seem to show up on android devices that use the default browser. In iOS and Opera Mobile it works as I'd expect.

Is there an additional method I can call that will cause the keyboard to show on Android's browser so the user can start typing right away?

```
function clear_search() {
    if($('#searchinput').val()) {
        $('#searchinput').val('');
    }
    $('#searchinput').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I think it can`t be done (at least until android 2.2) from javascript. If you are using phonegap you can use this here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/How-to-show-and-hide-soft-keyboard-in-Android

Comment: Even on android 2.2 @user1207504 's solution works if you use the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

this question is similar to 
[How to focus an input field on Android browser through javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858094/how-to-focus-an-input-field-on-android-browser-through-javascript-or-jquery)

Anyway, as you already have a click event to work with, this should sort you out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#field').click(function(e){ $(this).focus(); });

    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        $('#field').trigger('click');
    });
})
```

Of course you DO need a click event triggering this. Just focussing without an event doesnt seem to work. The above works for me on the standard browser on android 4 and shows the soft keyboard.

Comment: Just to note, this does not appear to work with a key press event (which is weird, because I would expect when focusing to a new text field using say, the tab or enter key, that the keyboard would display since I am focused on a text field...)

Comment: This works with touchstart + touchend events as well. Pretty nifty, as you could add a element on touchstart and trigger focus on touchend. Just remember to use event.stopPropagation(); and event.preventDefault(); as otherwise sometimes the keyboard will start showing and then hide again (depending on whats below the element triggering the event).

Answer (score 2):

`click()` on its own is **not enough**. You need to `focus()` then `click()`. Beware of endless loops if your script is triggered by an onclick() on a containing element. The script below is working for me on Chrome for android 58 and Safari mobile 602.1.

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

if (event.target != target) {
    target.focus();
    target.click();
}
```