# jQuery .focus() not working on android

Tags: android, jquery, html, focus, responsive-design

I'm developing a mobile website on Android where I have a select list as menu.

the select list is positioned outside the view area and I want to toggle the popup with the options on the browser by clicking a div.

I have already tried millions of ways to open the view to select a value, but none of them was successfull... After a little research I read on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858094/how-to-focus-an-input-field-on-android-browser-through-javascript-or-jquery/10243010#10243010) that the .focus() function is disabled on an android device.

I know this code works on IOS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation").click(function(){
        $("#mobileMenu").focus();
    });
});
```

with following html:

```
<select id="mobileMenu">
    <option value="link1" onclick='openMobileMenuLink' >link one</option>
    <option value="link2" onclick='openMobileMenuLink' >link two</option>
    <option value="link3" onclick='openMobileMenuLink' >link three</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way I can open the options perspective on the android device (I'm testing in chrome) without destroying the code (that works fine on IOS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

when tapped on a div, a click event is generated with js.

```
<div onclick="generateSelectDropDown()">
```

The above div calls following function:

```
window.generateSelectDropDown = function () { 
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('mobileMenu');
    showDropdown(dropdown);
};  

showDropdown = function (element) {
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, with the caveat that it is also deprecated. I used `element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'));` instead to achieve the same result without using the deprecated `initMouseEvent` method.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will still work in iOS, but it should...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation").click(function(){
        $("#mobileMenu").click();
    });
});
```