# jquery .focus safari & chrome mobile vs chrome mobile android

Tags: jquery, select, focus

on a mobile when you click the link "bring it up" this will bring up a dropdown menu in safari mobile (IOS) and  chrome mobile (IOS)  but nothing in chrome mobile (android)!

i just do `jQuery('#myselect').select().focus();`

Any clue on how i can achieve this little trick in both browser safari & chrome mobile IOS and **android**?

demo: http://bit.ly/10E3ScR

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .focus() not working on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756955/jquery-focus-not-working-on-android)