# Is it possible to open virtual keyboard forcefully?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

Is it possible to popup virtual keyboard when some command is being received  from server? I am  trying to call   focus on text area but soft keyboard is not coming. I agree that for keyboard to popup, user event is required.  Is there any way to show virtual keyboard forcefully? I am talking about  web app inside Android chrome browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593053/open-soft-keyboard-programmatically

Comment: Are you talking about a native app or a web app inside Android browser ?

Comment: @fiddler: a web app inside Android browser

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling `focus()` then `click()` on the input, but, as you say, only when the script is initiated by user input. My current answer, having spent a day fiddling, is that there is no way to get around this.

Comment: Thanks, "calling `focus()` then `click()` on the input" was precisely what I was looking for and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This question may help you: [Showing Android's soft keyboard when a field is .focus()'d using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020400/showing-androids-soft-keyboard-when-a-field-is-focusd-using-javascript)

In your case you could try to have a hidden text input field on your page and trigger a click event on it when the command is received from the server.

Answer (score -2):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

May this will help you