# Show android keyboard from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-softkeyboard, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to be able to show keyboard on mobile browser (e.g. Android) after navigating to the page.
I have already seen some workarounds:

[Show virtual keyboard on mobile phones in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837543/show-virtual-keyboard-on-mobile-phones-in-javascript)

[Can I trigger Android soft keyboard to open via javascript ( without phonegap )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457783/can-i-trigger-android-soft-keyboard-to-open-via-javascript-without-phonegap)

[Showing Android's soft keyboard when a field is .focus()'d using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020400/showing-androids-soft-keyboard-when-a-field-is-focusd-using-javascript)

But all of these examples work only if user tap somewhere. It allows to trigger `focus()` from within the `click()`. Does someone know if there any way to do the same thing but without user clicking?

I've tried to trigger click programmatically but it also not working. http://jsfiddle.net/alex_myronov/e5JcP/10/

Comment: EDIT: sorry misread the question.http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113168/2558344
Everything you would need is there^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to successfully open the virtual keyboard by just calling focus() method of the input.

It works in my app both on android 2.3 and 4.1.

I think the trick is that you have to wait untill the page is completly rendered before you call focus().

My app is using jquery mobile and I call focus() when the [pageshow event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) is triggered:

```
$("#myPage").on("pageshow", function( event ) {
        $("#myPage").find('input:first').focus();
} );
```

Or maybe it's working because I'm in a phonegap app?

Answer (score 2):

My current answer to this is no, can't be done. The script that calls focus() click() on an input needs to be running with user context, ie. triggered by a user interaction. After fairly dedicated fiddling, I've found no way round this.