# open keyboard and textbox same time on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I`m new in cordova/ phonegap project.
In my project i am making a android app. I want to make a search textbox to search item in given data. After clicking search button textbox and keyboard should open simultaneously.

In my project, I`m using html and javascript for native code.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Example:
search box should be like google play or whatsApp .

Comment: Check this once.. It will solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457783/can-i-trigger-android-soft-keyboard-to-open-via-javascript-without-phonegap

Comment: @user3150949 I checked the link and made changes but not working as expected. I have used fallowing library for extended search bar https://github.com/codrops/ExpandingSearchBar . This is working for IOS device but not working on Android device. Plz, have a look on js/uisearch.js and suggest me what should i do?