# Phonegap Android show keyboard on input focus Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, keyboard, tap

I have been searching for how to trigger the android keyboard via Javascript.

I have found a few answers but none of them seem to work.

One solution is here: 
[Showing Android's soft keyboard when a field is .focus()'d using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020400/showing-androids-soft-keyboard-when-a-field-is-focusd-using-javascript)

On the example above there is a button involved which I don't have, but do I need it?

I am using 'tap' and 'swipe' events via the touch-layer.js which seems to disable click events in favour of tap. (https://github.com/cubiq/touch-layer)

Below is the code I've tried, the alert triggers and the focus happens but the keyboard doesn't show.

```
gt("#txtEmail").on("tap", function() {
    alert('tap');
    $(this)[0].el[0].focus();
    $("#txtEmail").trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks.

EDIT 1: Second attempt doesn't work even though this seems more inline with the example.

```
gt("#txtEmail").on("tap", function() {
    alert('trigger');
    $("#txtEmail").trigger('click');
});

$("#txtEmail").on("click", function() {
    alert('recieved');
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jack He's suggstion, check out [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard). This one is more actively maintained and used by many.

In my case, I just bound `focus` event to a handler function that manually shows the keyboard.

```
$(".my-input").on("focus", function(e) {
  ...
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [SoftKeyBoard plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/726). Just check the link to find what you want.